# delay() or timeout with stop()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, delay

```
$('.file a').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#download').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#download').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

I want the `mouseenter` function to have a `stop()` and a delay of 1 second.
So, if I hover over `#download` the `fadeIn` should start after a 1 second delay. If I mouse out meanwhile the `fadeIn` shouldn't start. Get me?

I don't really know how to do that, any ideas?

Comment: @user239831 - Do you have an outstanding question on this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) in this case because of how [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) works (and your inability to cancel it).

```
$('.file a').live('mouseenter', function() {
  $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {
      $('#download').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
  }, 1000));
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
  $('#download').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5uUzE/).

If you use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) it'll dequeue the next animation for the element, *regardless of if you cleared that queue earlier*.  So you need a timeout that you *can* cancel, which the above does by manually calling [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) and storing the result with [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) so you can clear it later, via [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.clearTimeout).

Comment: Excellent. It is very important about delay. I still know of no way to cancel which means it should be used very carefully. This was a great way to deal with that. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I am trying the same in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZV5V/84/) for `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`, but doesn't work well. Can you please tell me what am I missing here? Note: I am trying to do it without using `hoverIntent()` function.

Comment: From the doco: _As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers._

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the answer to a similar question, and I found that .animate() could also be used to handle this, and it obeys .stop()

It would look something like this:

```
$('.file a').live('mouseenter', function() {
    $('#download')
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({opacity:0}, 1000);            // one second delay
        .animate({opacity:1}, 'fast', 'swing');
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#download')
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({opacity:0}, 'slow', 'swing');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a setTimeout function

```
$('.file a').live('mouseenter', function() {
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#download').stop(true, true).fadeIn('fast');
}, 1000);
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
    $('#download').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

setTimeout will execute the code inside the function after the specified miliseconds (in this case 1000).

Comment: You need to store/clear that timeout as well, if you hover in and out fast, it'll complete that fadeOut() (if it runs at all) in 200ms, then 800ms later have a queued fadeIn, even though you're not over the element.  Take a look here to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/T9t6N/ To test, quickly hover and leave the link.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this on jquery without using delay event .

```
$('.file a').hover(function() {
  time = setTimeout(function() {
     $('#download').fadeIn();
  },1000);
},function(){
    clearTimeout(time);
});
```

1000 is your time that after it $('#download') will fade in .