# jQuery delay() - how to stop it?

Tags: jquery, delay, settimeout, jquery-animate

I already tried stop(true,true), stop(true) and clearQueue(); but this doesn't work.

I have problem with fast changing slides, i already have some function what have to reset everything, but it doesn't work.

```
function reset(){
   $('div').clearQueue();
   $('#img').html('').css({'left':0,'right':0,'opacity':1,'z-index':1});
   $('#img2').html('').css({'left':0,'right':0,'opacity':1,'z-index':1});
   $('#place').html('');$('#place').html('<div id="img"></div><div id="img2"></div>');
}
```

But i thing this doesn't stop (or delete) delay() function on animations. So I don't know if i don't have to use setTimeout function.

Here is piece of animation script:

```
reset();
actual_slide=2;
  $('#img').html('<img src="'+image[4]+'" alt="Obrázek">').css({'opacity':0,'z-index':2}).delay(time_delay/5).fadeTo(time_fast,1).delay(time_delay*2).fadeTo(time_fast,0);
  $('#img2').html('<img src="'+image[3]+'" alt="Obrázek">').css({'opacity':'0','top':0}).fadeTo(time_fast,1).animate({'top':'-495'},time_delay*3,function(){
    if(actual_slide==2){$('#img2').css({'top':0}).fadeTo(time_fast*2,0).html('');}else{reset();}
    if(actual_slide==2){$('#img').html('<img src="'+image[3]+'" id="1" alt="Obrázek">').fadeTo(time_fast*2,'1').css({'left':-300,'top':-700}).animate({'left':-900,'top':-700},time_delay*2);}else{reset();}
    if(actual_slide==2){$('#1').css({'width':1365,'height':1200}).animate({'width':1665,'height':1400},time_delay*2);}else{reset();}
  });
```

That actual_slide have to protect it before repeating that function, but that doesn't work too.. Problem is when i fast changing slides, because that reset doesn't stop everything, and it start doing things what i don't want to have in (like change picture to other and other).

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6150 -- looks like they have fixed this in the jQuery 1.7 release candidate. Download that and see if it solves your problem, or read the bug report for some possible workarounds.

Comment: Also: possible duplicate of [jQuery: delay() or timeout with stop()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329197/jquery-delay-or-timeout-with-stop)

Comment: I've just try it and it's works with jQuery 1.8.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the jQuery [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) page:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Take a look at the [doTimeout](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) plugin; it may be what you are looking for.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tryed it with normal setTimeout and now it almost working. But now i just must somehow synchronize two timers.

Comment: I don't understand why the jQuery stop method wouldn't also stop a delay. +1 though - using the doTimeout plugin solved my issue.

Comment: Problem comes in when trying to use setTimeout with queues and animations because of requestAnimationFrame the two can get out of sync.

Answer (score 23):

You can break *.delay()* by *.dequeue()* function

here is example

```
//this is only for make sure that we skip 'delay', not other function
var inDelay = false;

function start()
{
    $('.gfx').animate
    ({
        width: 100
    }, function(){inDelay = true}).delay(3000).animate
    ({
        width: 0
    }, function(){inDelay = false})
}

function breakTheDelay()
{
    if(inDelay)
    {
        $('.gfx').dequeue();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/5288z/

//edit: more complex example provided with logging timestamps and cleanup ( without cleanup, multiple clicks on `Start` is unpredictable ) to prove that it works

http://jsfiddle.net/q0058whc/

or below

```js
//this is only for make sure that we skip 'delay', not other function
var inDelay = false;
var ltime = 0;

// console log will aways show 'end' values: 2000, 1000 an 400
// values may be different due to time wasted on calling functions
// sometimes delay is shorten by 0-200ms, it can be caused by js engine probably  

function start()
{
    cleanup();
    ltime = (1*new Date());
    $('.gfx').queue('fx', function(next)
    {
      logtime( 'animate1_start' );
     $('.gfx').animate
      ({
          width: 100
      }, 2000, function(){logtime('animate1_end');inDelay = true;})
      next();
    })
    .queue('fx', function(next)
    {
     logtime('delay_start');
     next()
    })
    .delay(1000)
    .queue('fx', function(next)
    {
     logtime('delay_end');
     next()
    })
    .queue('fx', function(next)
    {
     logtime('animate0_start');
     $('.gfx').animate
      ({
          width: 0
      }, function(){logtime('animate0_end');inDelay = false;})
      next()
    });
}

function cleanup()
{
  // remove current queue
    $('.gfx').clearQueue()
    // first animate runned interval. stop it 
    .stop()
    // reset width of element
    .css('width',0)
}

function logtime( name )
{
 var ntime = (1*new Date());
 console.log( name + ': ' + ( ntime - ltime ) );
  ltime = ntime;
}

function breakTheDelay()
{
    if(inDelay)
    {
        $('.gfx').dequeue();
    }
}

//
// version without 'inDelay' check only if you know what are you doing
// http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/hkw9H/
//
```

```css
.gfx
{
    background: red;
    width: 0;
    height: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="breakTheDelay()">Can't wait!</button>
<div class="gfx"></div>
```

Comment: If you play with this you will see that dequeue cancels the end result of the delay, but does not cancel the delay. In the example shown you can cancel the animation but if you click again within the 3 seconds the delay is still running and the animation cancels again.

Comment: no!
If you click "Can't wait!" during animation and then "Start" it will not work as you expected.

Wait fot animation complete then during delay press "Can't wait!" and "Start". It should go back and again animate width to 100px.

Comment: Nope, this does not work fully, just try to rapidly click those two buttons bunch of times than click start, animation will not wait proper time and will go forth and back immidietly or with some weird delay

Comment: this answer is not correct... the delay is not stopped. [demo](http://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/MKazpz). click prompt several times and keep clicking stop. It's not stopping the delay. withdraw my upvote.

Comment: @MaxYari, yes because `Start` don't care about current queue. Question was "How to stop .delay()", no "How to write application and protection from multiple clicks". If you wait for first animation end, then there is 3s delay. Click `Stop` to break it. I will add modified sample with more protections...

Answer (score 6):

Via [this post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/stop-does-not-clear-delay#14737000002193281) there's a very simple approach, which is to use `.animate` in place of `.delay`

Comment: Just as a reference, in case that page disappears, 'arniarent' wrote:

I found a way around the problem by using animate() as a replacement for delay():

`$('#element').stop(true,false).animate({opacity:1},200,'easeOutExpo').animate({opacity:1},2000).animate({opacity:0},1000,'easeInQuint');`

`animate({opacity:1},2000)` in this case works as `delay(2000)`, but is cancellable.

Comment: I used `.fadeTo(delayMs, 1)` which is a shorter version of the `.animate` call. I really wonder why the [delay bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6150) is marked fixed 4 years ago when it's still a problem, and also why `.delay` cannot just use animate under the hood to fix this.

Comment: delay bug IS fixed - you just need `stop(true)` because without it you're only stopping the delay and the rest of the queue can continue. `stop(false)` would make sense if you wanted to skip the delay only but then continue with the rest of the queued animations.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a user to rapidly restart an animation chain over and over again, sometimes in the middle of the animation. So instead of using `delay()` I animated to a bogus css propery `{"null":1}`. Here's a simple fade-in/fade-out. Seems to have worked for me!

```
//- fade in
$el.stop().animate({"opacity":1}, 200, "easeInSine", function(){
    //- delay for 2000ms
    $el.stop().animate({"null":1}, 2000, function(){
        //- fade out
        $el.stop().animate({"opacity":0}, 1000, "easeInOutSine", function(){
            //- final callback
        });
    });
});
```