# Cancel ongoing javascript intro on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a one page website where I use an introduction before showing the main content.
The introduction ( about ten seconds ) is triggered immediately and ends in this code:

```
// Fade in divs for intro

$('.intro-logo').fadeIn(800).delay(800, function() {
    $('.groupC').delay(400).fadeOut(800, function() {
        $('.main-holder').fadeIn(800);
        hash_handler();
        $('.footershow').delay(1600).fadeIn(800);
    });
});
```

During this event the hash_handler is triggered which scrolls the main page based on a # in the url in order to show the correct section of the page.

During the introduction a SKIP button is shown, when pressed follows this code:

```
function hideIntro() {
    $('.groupC').fadeOut(800);
    $('.main-holder').fadeIn(800);
    hash_handler();
    $('.footershow').delay(1600).fadeIn(800);
}
```

Please advice how to cancel the introduction when the SKIP button is pressed in order to avoid the hash_handler from being executed twice.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you're using jQuery. If correct, you can use the [`.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )` method](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) like this:

```
$('.groupC').stop(true, false).fadeOut(800);
```

The first argument determines whether jQuery cancels any pending animations for the object, while the second argument determines if jQuery jumps to the end of the current animation or leaves it where it is.

Comment: You will have to call `.stop(true, true)` on every object for which you have started animations. I'm sorry if that wasn't clear from my answer.

Comment: You might also have to call the `.dequeue()` function. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929266/jquery-delay-how-to-stop-it) for details.