# How do I clear an event call set using delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons, approve (visible) and undo(not visible). Clicking approve hides the button and shows the undo button (meant as a fail safe). Clicking approve sets a 20 second delay which will submit a form if realized. However I want the un-approve button to cancel the delay. How should I best do this without removing the event handler on the form entirely?

```
$("button.approve").on('click', function(e){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings('button.undo').show();
            $(this).siblings("form.update-comment.approve").delay(20000).trigger('submit');
        });

        $("button.undo").on('click', function(e){
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings('button.approve').show();
            $(this).siblings("form.update-comment.approve").off('submit');
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929266/jquery-delay-how-to-stop-it

Comment: `delay` works with effects and animations, not with `trigger` function.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the yellow box in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) ?

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—**it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay**—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Use a `setTimeout` instead

```
var approveTimeout;
$("button.approve").on('click', function(e){
    var self = $(this);
    self.hide().siblings('button.undo').show();
    approveTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        self.siblings("form.update-comment.approve").trigger('submit');
    }, 20000);
});

$("button.undo").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).hide().siblings('button.approve').show();
    clearTimeout( approveTimeout  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I forgot to add that I had multiple forms on the page so I used your code and added an object to track which setTimeout to cancel [code}var container = {};
            var forms = $(".update-comment.approve");
            forms.each(function (index){
                container['timeout'+index] = 0;
            });[/code]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`:

```
function onSubmit(form) {
    form.submit();
};

var delayedSubmit = null;

$("button.approve").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('button.undo').show();
    var thisForm = $(this).siblings("form.update-comment.approve");
    delayedSubmit = setTimeout(function() {
        onSubmit( thisForm );
    }, 2000);
});

$("button.undo").on('click', function(e){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('button.approve').show();
    clearTimeout( delayedSubmit );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var form = $("form.update-comment.approve")
, approve = $("button.approve")
, undo = $("button.undo");

form.on("submit.approved", function (e) {
    // do stuff
    undo.trigger("click", ["reset"])
});

approve.on('click', function (e) {
    approve.hide();
    undo.show();
    form
    .delay(20000, "approval")
    .queue("approval", function () {
        form.trigger('submit.approved');
    }).dequeue("approval");
});

undo.hide().on('click', function (e, reset) {
    form
    .queue("approval", []);
    undo.hide();
    approve.show();
    console.log(reset || "cancelled");  
});
```

See [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) , [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue)

```js
var form = $("form.update-comment.approve")
, approve = $("button.approve")
, undo = $("button.undo");

form.on("submit.approved", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert(e.namespace);
    undo.trigger("click", ["reset"])
});

approve.on('click', function (e) {
    approve.hide();
    undo.show();
    form
    .delay(20000, "approval")
    .queue("approval", function () {
        form.trigger('submit.approved');
    }).dequeue("approval");
});

undo.hide().on('click', function (e, reset) {
    form
    // clear queue
    .queue("approval", []);
    undo.hide();
    approve.show();
    console.log(reset || "cancelled");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" class="update-comment approve"></form>
<button class="approve">approve</button>
<button class="undo">undo</button>
```