# Understanding stop() and callbacks in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnqxkxgg/) with a function like this:

```
$("#success").stop(true, true).css({
    "top": offT,
        "opacity": 0
}).animate({
    "top": "-=40",
        "opacity": 1
}, 700, function () {
    $(this).delay(4000).animate({
        "opacity": 0
    }, 1200);
});
```

When you click a button once, there's no problem. But try clicking a button and after roughly two seconds click another. You'll notice that rather than delaying the fade out for 4 seconds, the div hides much sooner. In other words, the callback initiated by the first click is still active when clicking on the second button. I find this strange, because I call `stop(true,true)`. Doesn't this prevent the callback from the first click to be executed and finished? If not, how can I force it to do so?

Comment: You've bound the onClick function to both buttons. The first animation is stopped by the second button click, and the single #success div is then acted upon by the onClick of the second button.

Comment: @Daniel But why doesn't the `.stop` function on the second click prevent/disable/destroy the callback of the first click?

Comment: Set stop(true, true) to stop(true, false)

Comment: @Daniel This doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/fnqxkxgg/2/

Comment: Works fine for me. The div animates on first button press, then on second button press it moves to the second button and animates again before fading out after 4 seconds. What should it be doing?

Comment: @Daniel That's exactly what it should be doing, but it's not. Click a button, then another, and then another. Wait for the popup to almost fade out and then click the other button again. You'll notice that the button won't wait 4 seconds to fade out.

Comment: because you just use $(this).delay(4000)
it's just mean that it can't do anything until 4 second. So, if you wait longer than 2 seconds (ex. to 5 seconds, it will fade away immediately without need a click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should prevent the callback to be executed, but after your second click the callback has already been executed - the delay is in queue.

To prevent this you can use JS [`window.setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method and cancel the delay.

See this answer: [How to stop the delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7929399/4581323).

```
var delay;
$("button").click(function () {
    var offT = $(this).offset().top;
    window.clearTimeout(delay);
    $("#success").stop(true, false).css({
        "top": offT,
            "opacity": 0
    }).animate({
        "top": "-=40",
            "opacity": 1
    }, 700, function () {
        delay = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $("#success").animate({
                "opacity": 0
            }, 1200);
        }, 4000);
    });
});
```