# How to reset delay in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a slot machine, I want to show lines when someone clicks to add or 
subtract a line. I'm using the following code; the problem is that when someone clicks quickly (faster than delay time) it produce a bigger delay than expected. Here is a demostration (and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arglab/0f0rdoh7/1/))

[image: Bug]

```js
function arrowNumbers(id,min,max,difference){
 if ((min === undefined) || (min < 0)){
  min = 1;
 }
 if((difference === undefined)) {
  difference = 1;
 }
 var previousArrow = $('.'+id+' .previous');
 var nextArrow = $('.'+id+' .next');

 var screenNumbers = $('.'+id+' span');
 var actualNumber = $('.'+id+' span').text();

 var n = actualNumber;

 previousArrow.click(function(){
  if (n>min){
   if (parseInt(difference)>=parseInt(n))
    n = min;
   else
    n = parseInt(n)-parseInt(difference);
   showNumber(n);
   if (id=='line')
    showLines(n);
  }
 });

 nextArrow.click(function(){
  if (n<max){
   if (parseInt(difference)+parseInt(n)>max)
    n = max;
   else
    n = parseInt(n)+parseInt(difference);
   showNumber(n);
   if (id=='line')
    showLines(n);
  }
 });

 function showNumber(n){
  screenNumbers.text(n);
 }
}

function showLines(lines){
 var container = 'lines';
 var t = 1000;
 switch (lines) {
  case 20: $('.'+container+' .l.l-20').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 19: $('.'+container+' .l.l-19').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 18: $('.'+container+' .l.l-18').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 17: $('.'+container+' .l.l-17').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 16: $('.'+container+' .l.l-16').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 15: $('.'+container+' .l.l-15').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 14: $('.'+container+' .l.l-14').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 13: $('.'+container+' .l.l-13').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 12: $('.'+container+' .l.l-12').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 11: $('.'+container+' .l.l-11').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 10: $('.'+container+' .l.l-10').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 9: $('.'+container+' .l.l-9').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 8: $('.'+container+' .l.l-8').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 7: $('.'+container+' .l.l-7').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 6: $('.'+container+' .l.l-6').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 5: $('.'+container+' .l.l-5').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 4: $('.'+container+' .l.l-4').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 3: $('.'+container+' .l.l-3').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 2: $('.'+container+' .l.l-2').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
  case 1: $('.'+container+' .l.l-1').show(0).delay(t).hide(0);
 }
}

arrowNumbers('line',1,20);
```

```css
.lines {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.lines > .l { width:50px; height: 50px; color: #fff; float: left; background: #000; margin: 10px 0 0 0; display: none; }
.lines > .l:nth-child(2n){ background: rgba(0,0,0,.5); }

/* */

.line {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.line > .previous, .line > .next {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.line > span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="lines">
 <div class="l l-1">1</div>
 <div class="l l-2">2</div>
 <div class="l l-3">3</div>
 <div class="l l-4">4</div>
 <div class="l l-5">5</div>
 <div class="l l-6">6</div>
 <div class="l l-7">7</div>
 <div class="l l-8">8</div>
 <div class="l l-9">9</div>
 <div class="l l-10">10</div>
 <div class="l l-11">11</div>
 <div class="l l-12">12</div>
 <div class="l l-13">13</div>
 <div class="l l-14">14</div>
 <div class="l l-15">15</div>
 <div class="l l-16">16</div>
 <div class="l l-17">17</div>
 <div class="l l-18">18</div>
 <div class="l l-19">19</div>
 <div class="l l-20">20</div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="previous">
    <div class="arrow">pre</div>
  </div>
 <span>1</span>
 <div class="next">
   <div class="arrow">next</div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: This is because the `.delay()` events "stack" on each other in a queue and are not canceled on a new call. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929266/jquery-delay-how-to-stop-it)  (*possible duplicate*) to solve that problem.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Sorry for the delay, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arglab/0f0rdoh7/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay()` is not built to be able to stop and start.  Instead, use setTimeout and clearTimeout

**Replace your showLines function with this :**

```
var line_timers = {};
function showLines(lines){
    var container = 'lines';
    var t = 1000;
    for(var i=1;i<=20;i++) {
        var selector = '.'+container+' .l.l-' + i;
      clearTimeout(line_timers[selector]);
      if(i<=lines){
        $(selector).show(0);
        line_timers[selector]=setTimeout((function(x){
            return function(){
            $(x).hide(0);
          }
        })(selector),t);
      } else {
        $(selector).hide(0);
      }
    }
}
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/sm14hn79/

Comment: Here it is just replaced in your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/0f0rdoh7/2/

Answer (score 1):

try [dequeue](https://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)():

```
function showLines(lines){
    var container = 'lines';
    var t = 1000;
    $('.' + container).find('.l').dequeue().hide();
    switch() ...
}
```

Another option would be to replace delay, show and hide with fade/animate, setTimeout and simply use stop() and clearTimeout()

Comment: he uses fallthrough on the switch to show lines 1-lines though that could be solved with a `while(lines--)`

Comment: @trex005 ah, didnt notice the missing breaks :) thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Alex, but maybe I should try using fade/animate as you said. This happen using dequeue(): http://i.imgur.com/NBkFBVK.gif

Comment: @arglab yeah, that doesnt look sexy!