# jQuery animate() Sequence Out of Order when Hovering Speedily

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've created an animation with jQuery which sequentially (in reverse) slides in lines of texts. It's pretty simple and works great when hovering once. When rapidly moving the mouse around however, the lines will animate in a seemingly random order.

Please see the GIF below for a demonstration. The first hover is how the animation should look. After that hover, I moved my mouse in and out to demonstrate the issue with the text lines animating at random.

### [image]

Please see an example of my code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-block">
    <p>Text Line 1</p>
    <p>Text Line 2</p>
    <p>Text Line 3</p>
    <p>Text Line 4</p>
    <p>Text Line 5</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Hide text lines to begin with */
.image-block {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url('background-image.png');
}
.image-block p {
    position: absolute;
    left: -120%
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Animate text lines on hover with CSS 'left'.
    jQuery('.image-block').hover(function() {
        jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
        time = 0;
        speed = 300;
        jQuery(this).find('p').reverse().each(function() {
            jQuery(this).stop(true).delay(time).animate({
                left: '0'
            }, speed,
            function() {
                jQuery(this).stop(true).delay(time).animate({
                    left: '0'
                }, speed);
            })
            time = time + 125;
            speed = speed - 25;
        });
    }, function() {
        // Animate text lines on hover release with CSS 'left'.
        jQuery(this).find('p').reverse().each(function() {
            jQuery(this).stop(true).animate({
                left: '-120%'
            }, 150)
        });
    });
});
```

How is it possible for the top two lines to animate first when rapidly moving the mouse? Do I need to reset my animation somehow after hover has been released? I added `stop(true)` to the animation but this hasn't fixed the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A little tip, this kind of animation might be easier to do with CSS instead of jQuery

Comment: Didn't you already ask it? I seem to remember this gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got me scratching my head as well. As I've worked out this before, but for the sake of explanation had to go in detail.

The problem is with `.delay()` method which you're using with animation. When you add delay to animation, it can't be cleared. So when you hoverIn/hoverOut very fast, the handlers from previous hover events are not cleared and some `p` tags are animated out of order. For detailed explanation about `.delay()` check the selected answer here [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929266/jquery-delay-how-to-stop-it) or better [jQuery delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

About the solution to your problem. You can use `setTimeout` as a replacement for `delay`. I've made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ne5o11ds/4/) as a workaround to solve your problem using `setTimeout`.

You can do it this way with `setTimeout`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Animate text lines on hover with CSS 'left'.

  // To store setTimeout response
  var animations = new Array(5);

  jQuery('.image-block').hover(function() {
    jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
    time = 0;
    speed = 300;
    jQuery(this).find('p').reverse().each(function(index, item) {
            // Clear previous handlers
        clearTimeout(animations[index]);

        // Set new handlers and add to `animations`
        animations[index] = setTimeout(function(){
          jQuery(item).stop(true).animate({
            left: '0'
          }, speed);
        }, time);

        time = time + 125;
        speed = speed - 25;
    });

  }, function() {
    // Animate text lines on hover release with CSS 'left'.
    jQuery(this).find('p').each(function(index, item) {
            // Clear previous handlers
        clearTimeout(animations[index]);

        jQuery(item).stop(true).animate({
          left: '-120%'
        }, 150);
    });
  });
});
```

You need to save `setTimeout` return values to a variable when adding animation for hover(MouseIn), so that you can clear those at the time of MouseOut. If You need more explanation about the fiddle, please comment back.

**UPDATE:** `.clearQueue()` was not actually needed, so removed it and updated the fiddle code as well.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I'll test this out and get back to you with a correct answer mark :)