# How to break jQuery.delay in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.delay() and .setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407935/delay-and-settimeout)

Is there a way to break and stop javascript delay here ?

I want user when click on button this delay will stop and not execute the expected code like here

```
  $(#my_id).html('write my string here').delay(12000).fadeOut(1000) ;
```

so how can this be stopped to not fadeOut my string when user click on button with id `'my_button'` ?
any help is much appreciated

Comment: See this question, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329197/jquery-delay-or-timeout-with-stop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documentation for [jQuery.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) clearly states, you can't cancel delay configured using that function.

> [...] Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases  [...]

Use regular javascript [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to achive easily cancellable actions. For example your code could be transformed into:

```
$("#my_id").html('write my string here');
var myTimeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#my_id").fadeOut(1000);
}, 12000);

// to somewhere else cancel that timeout use clearTimeout function like so:
clearTimeout(myTimeoutId);
```

Comment: Delay is handled by setTimeout function. fadeOut will be issued after 12000 miliseconds, just as that would be when using jQuery.delay function.

Comment: ok seems settimeout will work when its cancellabe. thx

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not, if you [check out the documention](http://api.jquery.com/delay/). It is suggested that `setTimeout` could be an alternative to what you need.

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.